3D background showing up when using canvas_item shader in SubViewport
I have a scene setup where I'm trying to apply a color invert shader to the output of the SubViewport as such:

and shader code on ColorRect as such:
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D SCREEN_TEXTURE : hint_screen_texture, filter_linear_mipmap;

void fragment(){
    vec4 back_color = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, SCREEN_UV);
    COLOR = vec4(1.0 - back_color.rgb, back_color.a);
}

As you can see, along with the mesh the background is also being inverted and rendered despite Transparent BG being enabled
Is there any work around or another approach where only the mesh is rendered in the SubViewport with the shader effect applied?
Note:
The inverted shader is just for example, I want to be able to apply any canvas_item shader via this approach
